# line_item.value is not a valid group by expression

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I currently have two columns which is the result after flattening a json file in snowsql

```
discount     id
   10.00      1
   20.00      1
   10.00      2
   30.00      3
```

I want to introduce a third column that shows total discount for a particular id

```
id    total
1       30
2       10
3       30
```

Following is my code:

```
select
  line_item.value:product_id::varchar as id, 
  discount_allocation.value:amount::decimal(36,2) as discount,
  sum(discount) as total
from RAW_DATA_BUFFER,
  lateral flatten(input=>src:line_items) line_item,
  lateral flatten(input=>line_item.value:discount_allocations) discount_allocation
where record_type='shopify_order'
limit 10;
```

However, this gives error that `[LINE_ITEM.VALUE]` is not a valid group by expression

Comment: Some line-breaks would make it much easier to read the query.

Comment: Add a `group by` to your query, because `sum()` is an aggregate function, or use [`analytical function`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#window-syntax-and-usage)

Comment: I did add group by id but it gives another error "'DISCOUNT_ALLOCATION.VALUE' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause." @astentx

Comment: @HellyBhalodia Do you need to aggregate discount value to `product_id` or get the total along with every value of `discount`?

Comment: @astentx get the total along with every value of discount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have some additional "total" (of any kind, [supported functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#list-of-functions-that-support-windows) are listed in the documentation) column along with your original columns, you need to use [analytical function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#window-syntax-and-usage) here.

This way you need to put all the column to aggregate by in `partition by <column list>` clause and you do not need a `group by`.

```
select
  line_item.value:product_id::varchar as id, 
  discount_allocation.value:amount::decimal(36,2) as discount,
  sum(discount)
    over(
      partition by
        line_item.value:product_id,
        discount_allocation.value:amount
    ) as total
from RAW_DATA_BUFFER,
  lateral flatten(input=>src:line_items) line_item,
  lateral flatten(input=>line_item.value:discount_allocations) discount_allocation
where record_type='shopify_order'
limit 10;
```

Also it's possible to calculate totals on totals with

```
select
  display_cols,
  sum(column_to_aggregate) as aggregated_column_to_aggregate,
  sum(sum(column_to_aggregate))
    over(partition by columns_to_total_by) as total_column_to_aggregate
from your_table
group by group_by_cols
```

where the first `sum` calculates total grouped by `group_by_cols` and the second (outer) `sum` calculates an analytical function (totals) on aggregated result by `columns_to_total_by`. One notice: both `display_cols` and `columns_to_total_by` should be in `group_by_cols` columns since `group by` is executed first).

Answer (score 1):

You have an aggregation `SUM()` and two non-aggregated values - you should group by those two:

```sql
select
  line_item.value:product_id::varchar as id, 
  discount_allocation.value:amount::decimal(36,2) as discount,
  sum(discount) as total
from RAW_DATA_BUFFER,
  lateral flatten(input=>src:line_items) line_item,
  lateral flatten(input=>line_item.value:discount_allocations) discount_allocation
where record_type='shopify_order'
group by 1, 2
limit 10;
```

Comment: As a nicer alternative to `group by 1, 2` you can `group by id, discount`

Comment: thanks. Just one question though, is it necessary to add all the non-aggregated values in group by? like say we have 10 such non-aggregate columns then we'll have to include all of them?